# How to prevent IDEA from stopping debugger server after VM disconnect?

Tags: java, debugging

I've stumbled upon perfect developer environment problem™ - i've successfully put everything i want into Docker containers and debugging my service using IDEA remote debug which starts a server for JDWP agent. The problem is, every time JVM disconnects from IDEA's debugger server, the latter one dies, and every `docker-compose restart X` shuts down JVM and ends up in JDWP agent error because it simply can't connect to debugger server. Is there a way to prevent such behavior and keep IDEA's debugger server on after JVM disconnect?